# How to append several lines when iterating through List?

Tags: c#, list, text-parsing

I'd appreciate if someone could advise on the following.

I read the file containing the below text and writing each line into the `List<string>`:

```
CODE/1
NAME/some_name1
SHORT_NAME/short_name1   
CODE/2
NAME/document is a piece of paper 
containing information often 
used as proof of something
SHORT_NAME/document is a piece
```

Now I'm parsing the list to get `CODE, NAME and SHORT_NAME` separately.
The problem is that some lines containing `NAME` have one sencence which is broken into several lines due to its long length. I want to append these lines into one sentence, the output should be:

```
...
NAME/document is a piece of paper containing information often used as proof of something
...
```

My code appends only one next line:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(path).ToList();
List<string> full_lines = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in lines)
         {               
            if (line.StartsWith("NAME"))
            {

                name_index = lines.IndexOf(line);
                string new_line = "";
                if (!lines.ElementAt(name_index + 1).StartsWith("SHORT_NAME")) //checking if   
                //the next line does not start with SHORT_NAME (then it is continuation of NAME)
                {                       
                    new_line = line + " " + lines.ElementAt(name_index + 1);//appending the next
                                                                            //line
                    full_lines.Add(new_line); //adding into new list
                }                   
                else
                {                        
                    full_lines.Add(line);
                }
            }
          }
```

So the output is:

```
 ...
NAME/document is a piece of paper
...
```

So, how can I append all lines?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 if (!lines.ElementAt(name_index + 1).StartsWith("SHORT_NAME")) //checking if   
                //the next line does not start with SHORT_NAME (then it is continuation of NAME)
                {                       
                    new_line = line + " " + lines.ElementAt(name_index + 1);//appending the next
                                                                            //line
                    full_lines.Add(new_line); //adding into new list
                }                   
                else
                {                        
                    full_lines.Add(line);
                }
```

to

```
     new_line = line;
     name_index++;
     while (!lines.ElementAt(name_index).StartsWith("SHORT_NAME"))                       
     {                       
     new_line = new_line + " " + lines.ElementAt(name_index);//appending the next line
     name_index++;
     }  

     full_lines.Add(new_line);
```

Comment: Thank you, works good, but it also appends the line that contains SHORT_NAME. The result is: NAME/document is a piece of paper containing information often used as proof of something SHORT_NAME/document is a piece

Comment: sorry there was a mistake in incrementing, try the edit

Comment: it works wrong now, I removed increments and added condition into while()  if (!lines.ElementAt(name_index).StartsWith("SHORT_NAME")). So it works fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you're reading the file, read each line separately, instead of all them together.  Then don't create a new line unless it starts with a key word or if the '/' is unique unless the line contains a '/'.  Something like this might help:

```
List<string> full_lines = new List<string>();
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
string line = "";
while(!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    if(!line.Contains("/"))
    {
        full_lines[full_lines.Count - 1] += line;
    }
    else
        full_lines.Add(line);
}
```